# As a bulk sender, is there a way to make Gmail show my avatar?

Tags: marketing, gmail, bulk-email

As a bulk sender, is there a way to make Gmail show my avatar?

[image]

I would like to obtain this without creating a Google Account.

Maybe embedding my vCard? Or maybe [embedding some json-ld markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview)?

Comment: Just an observation... The avatar the receiver sees either appears to come from the receivers own (Google) address book, or from the senders Google+ profile. HOWEVER, there is one (only one) email I do receive regularly (it is sent directly to my email address) that does include an avatar and the sender is not in my address book nor is it from a Gmail address. The avatar does not appear to be embedded in the email. So, it's not obvious where this image is coming from. It might still be coming from their Google+ profile, which is linked to from their website?

Comment: In fact, examining the Gmail UI, it does appear this avatar is being linked from Google+. So, it would seem a Google Account probably is necessary.

Comment: Why would creating a Google account be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

The avatar is powered both through the recipients own address book as well as through Google+ This works by making sure your Google+ email and domain name match the sender email address that the gmail recipient sees and that you have a default avatar defined for your Google+ profile. When this is done then you should see that the avatar is in the recipients gmail inbox.