# How do I get email clients, other than Gmail, to show my company avatar beside my emails in inboxes?

Tags: email, branding

I have noticed in my inbox that a number of companies have their avatar/logo displayed next to their address/message snippet.

This is true in a number of email clients that I have used - Gmail, Outlook, Thunderbird, Blue mail...

I have searched online and all info seems to be relating to Gmail.

I am keen to find out for my own business...

Gmail appears easy and there is a lot of literature on the web showing how to do this.

I am keen to find out how to have my avatar show on the other email clients:
blue mail, Thuderbird, Outlook etc

Where do they pick up my companies email avatar from?

Any help surrounding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: @stephen Ostermiller - You have marked my question as a duplicate and I can see understand to a certain extent. However, my question is not specific to google. You will see from my question, however, that I am not looking for Gmail details. I am mopre concerned with other email clients. there is information all over the web relating to gmail. I want to know how to have my avatar show on outlook, thunderbird, bluemail etc

Comment: For Gmail, the answer is here: [As a bulk sender, is there a way to make Gmail show my avatar?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100123/as-a-bulk-sender-is-there-a-way-to-make-gmail-show-my-avatar)    I've re-opened this so it can be answered for other email providers.